# Save LAST number of line as setcounter/newcommand (lineno)

Tags: lineno, setcounter

My goal is to save the last number of the line in the enviroment `\begin{linenumbers} ... \end{linenumbers}` (which is in this example 3) as a counter or newcommand (or something similar). How can i get the "3"?

```
\documentclass[11pt,german]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault,condensed,light]{roboto}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcounter{mylineno}
\newcommand{\mylineno}{}

\usepackage{lineno}
\renewcommand{\makeLineNumber}{\llap{\linenumberfont\rlap{\LineNumber}\hspace*{-5 mm}}}
\renewcommand{\linenumberfont}{\footnotesize}

%\setcounter{mylineno}{\LineNumber} <- doesnt save the counter as "3"
%\renewcommand{\mylineno}{\LineNumber} <- doesnt save the newcommand as "3"

\begin{document}
\begin{linenumbers}
\modulolinenumbers[1]
        
\resetlinenumber
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
    
\end{linenumbers}
\end{document}
```

Here is what i get in the PDF document:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lineno}

\newcounter{lastlineno}
\def\lastlinenumber{%
  \setcounter{lastlineno}{\value{linenumber}}%
  \addtocounter{lastlineno}{-1}%
  \thelastlineno}

\begin{document}

\begin{linenumbers}
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
\end{linenumbers}

\lastlinenumber

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can hook in the `linenumbers` environment.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault,condensed,light]{roboto}
\usepackage{lineno}

\AddToHook{env/linenumbers/after}{%
  \xdef\thelastlineno{\the\numexpr\value{linenumber}-1\relax}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{linenumbers}
\modulolinenumbers[1]
\resetlinenumber
some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text
\end{linenumbers}

The previous paragraph had \thelastlineno\ lines.

\end{document}
```

[image]